# Is WebDAV a commonly-used, standard protocol?

Tags: webdav

Is WebDAV a commonly-used, standard protocol?

Comment: I doubt it's THE standard protocol.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Yes, it is a standard protocol](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4918.txt) and [it is widely used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV). Windows, Mac OS X and Linux do support it, [SubVersion](http://subversion.tigris.org) uses it as one of its primary protocols, and there are countless other examples.

Comment: @Julian Reschke: You're right, I didn't realize that 4918 obsoleted 2518. Corrected the link.